# Calculating height on heightmap

Tags: java, math, camera, height, heightmap

Like in topic. I have heightmap generated and I want to calculate exact height on single heightmap square. Each square have 4 heights, one for each corner.

For example:

```
0---4   4---4
-----   -----
--A--   --A--
-----   -----
0---0   0---0
```

In both cases point A should be at height 2.

```
8---4   4---4   0---8
-----   -----   -----
--B--   --B--   --B--
-----   -----   -----
0---0   4---4   8---0
```

In every case point B should be at height 4.

```
8---4   8---8
-----   -----
--C--   --C--
-----   -----
4---8   4---8
```

In both cases point C should be at height 6.

I think that the correct formula for any point in the middle (like A, B, C) is (pseudocode):

```
00 = bottom left corner height
10 = bottom right corner height
01 = top left corner height
11 = top right corner height

height = (Math.min(00, 10, 01, 11)+Math.max(00, 10, 01, 11))/2;
```

How can I calculate this height for any point in any place?

Comment: If the upper left is 2 for the second map, then what should be the height of A?

Comment: In this case A height will be 2, too.

Comment: So the line from the top-left corner to A in @Ziyao's case would be flat?  That doesn't make sense - more specific information is needed to produce an algorithm here.  There are multiple ways to extrapolate height information between just 4 defined points.

Comment: More informations added.

Comment: This is what I am asking for (but for all points, not only point in the middle).

Comment: I added the correct formula for any point in the middle.

Comment: Have you read: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bilinear_interpolation?

Comment: Bilinear interpolation is also what came into my mind immediately, but it will not produce all your example results, e.g. A will be 1 in the first example. If that is not acceptable then you probably have to provide more information what values in the non-center points you expect.

Comment: If you are certain that you want the center point to be the mean of the max and min corners, then the most reasonable way to extrapolate to other points might be to divide the space into four triangles in 3d space (two corner points and the center) and interpolate on their surface.

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem can be solve via bilinear interpolation between the corner points of every square.